# Array index out of range exception in future task

Tags: java

In the following method, I get an exception:

```
public static Ticket executeOrder(final FXOrderData orderData)
      throws Exception {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future<Ticket> ticketFuture = service.submit(new Callable<Ticket>() {
      @Override
      public Ticket call() throws Exception {
        try {
          if (isSwap(orderData)) {
            return FXOrderManager.getInstance().executeFXSwapOrder(orderData);
          } else {
            return FXOrderManager.getInstance().executeFXOrder(orderData);
          }
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
          Log.error(getClass().getName(), "executeOrder",
              "Unable to execute order : " + e.getMessage(), e);
          throw new FXMOEException( e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    });

    return ticketFuture.get();
  }
```

What are the possible cases where this exception will be thrown from the future task? Here is the corresponding **stack trace**:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Array index out of range: 0
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at com.indigo.neuron.gui.manualorderentry.ManualOrderUtils.executeOrder(ManualOrderUtils.java:146)
    at com.indigo.neuron.gui.manualorderentry.ManualOrderPanel$6$1.run(ManualOrderPanel.java:761)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: Array index out of range: 0
    at com.indigo.neuron.gui.manualorderentry.ManualOrderUtils$2.call(ManualOrderUtils.java:141)
    at com.indigo.neuron.gui.manualorderentry.ManualOrderUtils$2.call(ManualOrderUtils.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    ... 3 more
```

The issue is happening in the call of this method:

```
public Ticket executeFXOrder(FXOrderData fxOrderData) throws Throwable {
    validateOrder(fxOrderData);
    // execute non-swap order.

    StrategyInfo strategyInfo = FXStrategyController.getInstance().createStrategy(fxOrderData);
    String strategyID = strategyInfo.getWaveID();
    FXStrategyController.getInstance().startStrategy(strategyInfo);
    String basketId = fxOrderData.getBasketID();

    if (StringUtils.isNullOrWhitespace(basketId)) {
        String symbol = fxOrderData.getSymbol();
        String side = fxOrderData.getSide();
        boolean contra = fxOrderData.isContraTrade();
        String currency = SymbolUtils.getDealCurrency(fxOrderData.getSymbol(), fxOrderData.isContraTrade());

        BasketCollection bc = ZConnection.getBasketStore();
        bc = (BasketCollection) bc.filter(new STBFilter(symbol, side, currency, contra));

        if (bc.size() > 0) {
            basketId = (String) bc.keySet().iterator().next();
        }
    }

    BasketCollection store = ZConnection.getBasketStore();
    Basket basket = store.get(basketId);

    if (basket != null) {
        Wave wave = basket.getWave(strategyID);
        if (wave != null) {
            return (Ticket) wave.getTickets().get(0);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The strange thing is that it only happens when running and not when debugging.

Comment: If you try to acces an array at index `n` where index `n` is bigger or equal then the size of the array..., or if it is negativ.

Comment: Just curious: Are you planning to do this asynchronously? I don't see why you have this executed in a seperate Thread when you right after submitting wait for it to finish?

Answer (score 2):

Most like the cause of the exception is in the line of code in the last sections marked "Caused by:"

This being

```
Caused by: Array index out of range: 0
    at com.indigo.neuron.gui.manualorderentry.ManualOrderUtils$2.call(ManualOrderUtils.java:141)
    at com.indigo.neuron.gui.manualorderentry.ManualOrderUtils$2.call(ManualOrderUtils.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
```

Note: the first exception is just a wrapping exception to say where the true exception was caught and rethrown.

In short, always read the last portion of the stack trace first.

Comment: This issue is happening at the line   return FXOrderManager.getInstance().executeFXOrder(orderData);

Comment: Guessing where the stack trace points to: ``(Ticket) wave.getTickets().get(0)``?

Comment: yes.  Ticket t = null;
      if(wave.getTickets().size() !=0){
        t = (Ticket) wave.getTickets().get(0);
      }
Having this check solved the pbm. But i feel it is not the correct way to do it.